# Meteor signed release apk can't connect to server

Tags: android, meteor

I am new to meteor. My apologies in advance if the question sound stupid.

When I build my meteor app with --debug option and install the android app manualy on my phone everythings work perfectly . If I build it without  --debug and sign + ziplign  and  install it , it can't connect to server . 
Please kindly help me .

Answer (score 1):

you can can follow these stpes simply.
To build your Meteor App(Note:to be set mobile.config file ) .

```
meteor build ../output_ditectory/projectname --server=<your_server_address>
```

Threre After You point the *output_directory* .created tar file and Andorid Folder.Inside Andorid Folder to see ***release-unsigned.apk*** . this apk was unsigned. You Can sign using **Zip-align**.

And Follow the Tutorial [Here](https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#submitting-android). Any Doubt About My answer Please Comment Here.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I followed extalty  these steps and I am still not able to connect to my server. However if I build using  comand bellow everythings work as supposed to do . 

meteor build --debug ../output_ditectory/projectname --server=<your_server_address>

Comment: hello, you got answer ?

Comment: I am still searching for a solution

Comment: where is the stuck ? build is not completed ?